# In asp.net mvc 4.0 Multiple save methods not working in api controller

Tags: asp.net, json, api, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I am working with asp.net MVC 4.0,In my API Controller I am having two save methods which are called through AJAX calls.The issue is both of them are not working simultaneously i.e the method doesn't get called.
If i comment one the other works fine

Sample Code of APIController:

```
[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Model1> Save1 (Model1 model1)
{
    //code
}


[HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<Model2> Save2(Model2 model2)
{

}
```

Code of json :

```
 $.ajax
         ({
             url: "/api/Myapi/Save1",                 
             type: 'POST',
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: JSON.stringify(model1),
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("success");

                 return true;
             }
         });
```

similar code for Save2  Method
Please suggest.

Comment: Show `WebApiConfig.cs` file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to violate the standard RESTful routing convention and use custom names for your actions you will have to define a custom route in your `WebApiConfig` containing the `{action}` part in it:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The RESTful routing convention dictates that you should have a single action per HTTP verb and per resource (i.e API controller).

Comment: Hi Darin Dimitrov, Actually i am new to asp.net mvc 4.could you please explain what should i add in WebApiConfig so that both my save methods will work..

Comment: both are post, your issue is related to the route meta data